# On R, show that the family of normal distribution is a location scale family

Tags: normal-distribution

I don't know how to show it on R

Let $X$ have a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Notation: $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  By definition, its probability density function (pdf) is
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi\,\sigma^2}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\,\sigma^2)}, ~~ -\infty<x<\infty. 
$$

Show that the family of normal distribution is a location-scale family where μ is the location parameter,
 is the scale parameter, and standard distribution of the family and the standard normal, i.e. a normal
with mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.

The only hint I saw is This means that $X=\sigma\,Z+\mu\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, if $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X=\sigma\,Z+\mu$ with $Z\sim N(0,1)$ then using the properties of expectation and variance it follows that

$$E(X)=\mu$$

$$V(X)=\sigma^2$$

and in fact using a change of variable when integrating the density it can be shown that $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Hence any normal random variable can written in the form $X=\sigma\,Z+\mu$ with $Z\sim N(0,1)$. The location paramater is $\mu$ and the scale parameter is $\sigma$.